# Usage of the definite article in "(The) residents in this town want to keep the town clean"

Tags: definite-article

Can anyone please tell me if I can omit **the** in the following sentence? I want to know if it is essential in the following sentence, and why yes, or why not?

> **(The)** residents in this town are very genial and they want to keep the town clean.

Comment: In short, YES! And while **residents in** is perfectly correct, Ngram indicates that **residents of** is three times as popular.

Comment: @RonaldSole Would you interpret the above sentence as stated (with *in* instead of *of*) with the article as suggesting a contrast between the residents and some other group (as perhaps previously disambiguated)?

Comment: @userr2684291 A typical English speaker wouldn't make any distinction between residents **in** and **of**, nor even notice whether you introduced the sentence with **the**. You are looking for nuances that few would be aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definite article ('the') specifies.

Residents of Smallville speak Latin - an unspecified number of residents greater than one can speak Latin.

The residents of Smallville speak Latin - all of the residents speak Latin.

Comment: *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (Huddleston & Pullum 2002) says the following on page 370: "In [*The bathroom tiles are cracked.*] it is not necessarily the case that every individual tile is cracked: rather, the totality of the tiles gives the impression of being cracked. If I wish to indicate that every individual tile is cracked, I must make that explicit, for example by adding the universal quantifier *all* as a predeterminer." Would you not make a similar observation in the given example?